# How to clear an object of list after it gets processed once with iterator

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, collections

I have one method which is writing is **processing csv file** as below:

```
public void processFile(Mapper mapper) {
    List<OutputCsvDataDto> outputDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<List<AddressDto>> iter = this.addressLists.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        List<AddressDto> listOfAddress = iter.next();
        for (AddressDto address : listOfAddress) {
            this.csvOut = new OutputCsvDataDto();
            this.csvOut=set.data ;
            this.csvOut=set.value ;
            this.processDataToResultantCsv(outputDataList);
        }
    }
}
```

In `processDataToResultantCsv` method I am writing below code

```
public void processDataToResultantCsv(List<OutputCsvDataDto>outputDataList){
    Iterator<String> filesIterator = this.getOutgoingFileName().iterator();
    while(filesIterator.hasNext()) {
        String fileName = filesIterator.next();
        for (List<AddressDto> addressList : this.addressLists) {
            for (AddressDto addressListnew : addressList) {
                for (OutputCsvDataDto output : outputDataList) {
                    if (addressListnew.equals(output.getAddress())) {
                        this.writer.writeToCsv(outputDataList, fileName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        filesIterator.remove(); //Removes it from the List<String> 
    }
}
```

Here in `processDataToResultantCsv` file I am sending parameter `outputDataList` 
  which has data and value. The issue here is that suppose my filesIterator 
  object has 10 values then all filename files gets processed with same data and 
  value.Here in first round of iteration suppose I have 3 arraylist in addressList then in second for loop addressListnew will compare one single object with outputdatalist object.I want to remove this object once writeToCsv method is being called.so that in while(filesIterator.hasNext()) when again this object appears it does not get write again for a new filename.Please help me where I am doing it wrong.I am not good with collections so using for loop for iteration

Comment: you haven't added an element to `outputDataList `